# R - get all pairs of values with same ID

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr, reshape, data-manipulation

I'm having trouble manipulating data in the way I need to. Take the following sample data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(id=factor(c(1,1,1,2,2,3)), person=c('P1','P2','P3','P4','P1','P3'))

  id person
1  1     P1
2  1     P2
3  1     P3
4  2     P4
5  2     P1
6  3     P3
```

I want to generate a data frame containing each possible pair of `person` within each `id`, *all* unique arrangements included (i.e., `P1`-`P2` and `P2`-`P1` are unique). For example:

```
  id  person1  person2
1  1       P1       P2
2  1       P1       P3
3  1       P2       P1
4  1       P2       P3
5  1       P3       P1
6  1       P3       P2
7  2       P4       P1
8  2       P1       P4
9  3       P3       NA
```

Note: Notice `id` '3' and `person` 'P3' does not have any other matching persons, and thus has an NA in the `person2` column of the final data frame. Though this is highly desired, if it's not possible or incredibly difficult, I will take responses which just omit `id` 3 or just match the `P3` value with itself (e.g., `P3`-`P3`).

Let me know if I'm not articulating this well, I would be happy to elaborate. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a `merge` on `df` with itself using `id` as the key. However, it will show persons matching with itself (e.g. `P1-P1`, `P2-P2`, etc.). You can remove those rows afterwards.

```
# Data in question
df <- data.frame(id=factor(c(1,1,1,2,2,3)), 
                 person=c('P1','P2','P3','P4','P1','P3'))

# Merge with itself
df2 <- merge(df, df, by = "id", suffixes = c("1", "2"), all.x = TRUE)

   id person1 person2
1   1      P1      P1
2   1      P1      P2
3   1      P1      P3
4   1      P2      P1
5   1      P2      P2
6   1      P2      P3
7   1      P3      P1
8   1      P3      P2
9   1      P3      P3
10  2      P4      P4
11  2      P4      P1
12  2      P1      P4
13  2      P1      P1
14  3      P3      P3

# Remove self matches
subset(df2, person1 != person2)

   id person1 person2
2   1      P1      P2
3   1      P1      P3
4   1      P2      P1
6   1      P2      P3
7   1      P3      P1
8   1      P3      P2
11  2      P4      P1
12  2      P1      P4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the merge function to merge the data.frame to itself like this:

```
new.df=unique(merge(df, df, by='id'))
```

Follow it with a subset function to exclude anything with the same person in both columns:

```
final.df=subset(new.df, person.x!=person.y)
```